# Issue with if and else statement in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Hi I'm having an issue checking through a list codes that are stored in a temp dictionary and matching ones that exist and if one doesn't exist then print/await a different result. I'm doing this by comparing the uses for each invite before the user joined and after they joined.

It seems as if the if statement `if invite.uses < find_invite_by_code(invites_after_join, invite.code).uses:` is being ignored and the else statement is being printed/awaited instead for both expired and none expired code. I'm not too sure why this is happening. Help would be appreciated.

I have commented parts of the code for a better understanding.

Here is my code:

```
invites = {} #temporary dict to store the codes


# A function to find an invite in a guilds.invites() list

def find_invite_by_code(invite_list, code):

# Simply looping through each invite in an
# invite list which we will get using guild.invites()

    for inv in invite_list:
    
        # Check if the invite code in this element
        # of the list is the one we're looking for
    
        if inv.code == code:
        
            # If it is, we return it.
        
            return inv

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, member):
    time = datetime.utcnow()
    users = len([e.name for e in member.guild.members])
    name = member
    name = " ~ ".join((name.name, name.nick)) if name.nick else name.name
    
    # Getting the invites before the user joining
    # from our cache for this specific guild
    invites_before_join = invites[member.guild.id]
    
    # Getting the invites after the user joining
    # so we can compare it with the first one, and
    # see which invite uses number increased
    invites_after_join = await member.guild.invites()

    # Loops for each invite we have for the guild
    # the user joined.
    for invite in invites_before_join:

        # Now, we're using the function we created just
        # before to check which invite count is bigger
        # than it was before the user joined.
        if invite.uses < find_invite_by_code(invites_after_join, invite.code).uses:
            
            # Now that we found which link was used we'll start the embed 
            joinmsg = discord.Embed(title=f'{member.name}#{member.discriminator} has joined', timestamp=time, colour=discord.Color(random.randint(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF)))
            joinmsg.add_field(name="**Account Created:**", value=member.created_at.strftime("%#d %b %Y, at %I:%M%p"), inline=True)
            joinmsg.add_field(name="**Invite:**", value=f"||{invite.code}||", inline=True)
            joinmsg.add_field(name="**Inviter:**", value=f"{invite.inviter}", inline=False)
            joinmsg.set_footer(text=f"Member {users} • User ID: {member.id}")
            joinmsg.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
            await self.bot.send_log_message(member.guild, embed=joinmsg)
            
            #We use an else statement if a NoneType is returned this would happen if the invite link has expired.
        else:
            # Create the embed to be sent
            joinmsg = discord.Embed(title=f'{member.name}#{member.discriminator} has joined', timestamp=time, colour=discord.Color(random.randint(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF)))
            joinmsg.add_field(name="**Account Created:**", value=member.created_at.strftime("%#d %b %Y, at %I:%M%p"), inline=True)
            joinmsg.add_field(name="**Invite:**", value=f"Expired", inline=True)
            joinmsg.set_footer(text=f"Member {users} • User ID: {member.id}")
            joinmsg.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)

            await self.bot.send_log_message(member.guild, embed=joinmsg)
        
            # We will now update our cache so it's ready
            # for the next user that joins the guild
            invites[member.guild.id] = invites_after_join 
            # return to prevent looping when we already got what we want
            return
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like something isn't happening quite the way you want it to, I would add a `print` function before it and print the values of `invite.uses` and `find_invite_by_code(invites_after_join, invite.code).uses` and then print the `type` of them too, if you still can't spot the error, then we'll have a problem

```
print(invite.uses, find_invite_by_code(invites_after_join, invite.code).uses)
print(type(invite.uses), type(find_invite_by_code(invites_after_join, invite.code).uses))
```

Comment: Thank you, so with this I find it's only returning the value of `invite.uses` for one invite which is `61 61`and `type` `<class 'int'> <class 'int'>`

Comment: Ok so it looks like you want to add an `<=` because it looks like its skipping it because they are the same

Comment: `<=` as in `if invite.uses <= find_invite_by_code(invites_after_join, invite.code).uses:`?

Comment: Yeup exactly :))

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. :D

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)